# How can I generate something in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I want to create a truth or dare generator using Kivy. I have finished all the designing but I have one problem. When I click the button generate I want it to pick a random dare or truth from my text files that I have. One of my text files is called "dares.txt" and "truths.txt". How can I make it so that when the user clicks generate it shows a random dare or truth from my text files below. Here is my code for the truth or dare app so far.

**main.py file:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import json, glob
from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path
import random

Builder.load_file('design.kv')

class LoginScreen(Screen):
    def sign_up(self):
        self.manager.current = "sign_up_screen"

    def login(self,uname,pword):
        with open("users.json") as file:
            users = json.load(file)
        if uname in users and users[uname]['password'] == pword:
            self.manager.current = "login_screen_success"
        else:
            self.ids.login_wrong.text = "Sorry, The Username Or Password You Entered was Incorrect. Please Try Again!"

class RootWidget(ScreenManager):
    pass

class SignUpScreen(Screen):
    def add_user(self,uname,pword):
        with open("users.json") as file:
            users = json.load(file)

        users[uname] = {'username': uname, 'password': pword,
            'created': datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")}
        
        with open("users.json", 'w') as file:
            json.dump(users,file)
        self.manager.current = "sign_up_screen_success"

class SignUpScreenSuccess(Screen):
    def go_to_login(self):
        
        self.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
        self.manager.current = "login_screen"

class LoginScreenSuccess(Screen):
    def log_out(self):
        self.manager.transition.direction = "right"
        self.manager.current = "login_screen"       

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

**design.kv file**:

```
<LoginScreenSuccess>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        padding: 30, 30
        spacing: 30, 30
        Button:
            color: 1, 0, 0, 1
            text: "Quit App"
            on_press: root.log_out()
        Label:
            text: "Truth or Dare?"
        TextInput:
            hint_text: "Two Things To Try: Truth or Dare"
        Button:
            text: "Generate"
            #on_press: root
        ScrollView:
        Label:
            text: ""
            #text_size = self.width, None
            #size_hint_y: None
            #height: self.texture_size[1]
```

If anyone could help and tell me what to do exactly that would be awesome! I would like to know how when the button is clicked it can display text or a random truth or dare when the user types 'truth' or 'dare' in the textbox.

Comment: If you read your `dares.txt` and store it as a list of `dares`, then you can just do `random.choice(dares)` to get a random selection.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I appreciate the help.